# Icefaces 1.8 look and feel issue

Tags: java, jsf, user-interface, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I am not able to figure out how to get a good look and feel for the `header` of an icefaces datatable component. I have used the `ice:commandSortHeader` but the images (i.e. arrows) are not getting displayed at all. Also the header does not have a `shiny` look and feel in it like the component showcase is having.

I am trying to use the `rime.css`, hence added this line:

```
<link href="css/rime.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I used `ice:graphicImage` for the paginator and the images as well as the look and feel is fine. For the Sortable header, I have added the arrow images in my workspace but not able to understand where to add it for making it display. Also don't know how to bring the `shiny` look and feel for the header.

Please help me out with the header look and feel issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<link href="css/rime.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

with

```
<ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```